# FindControl wont work on dynamic check boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

Find control doesn't seem to work with my dynamic check boxes; what i am trying to do is see if a user has checked a check box, eventually which ones as well.

In my code i have a test to see if it is working properly

```
 public void test()
{
    // Find control on page.
    CheckBox myControl1 = (CheckBox)Table1.FindControl("CBX0");
    if (myControl1 != null)
    {
        // Get control's parent.
        Control myControl2 = myControl1.Parent;
        Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " + myControl2.ID);
        if (myControl1.Checked == true)
        {
            Response.Write("check box checked");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Control not found");
    }
}
```

when i run my code it does print "parent of the text box is", however it will not print the parent, which is supposed to be mycontrol2.id

Comment: considering what you wrote myControl2 can not be Null. At this point can ID be empty?

Comment: Can you post the code of Table1? and the code that how are you calling the test method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the parent control doesn't have an ID.

Instead try:

```
Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " + myControl2);
```

to find out the type of the Parent. I think if you're expecting the parent to be the Table you're wrong. It will probably be a TableCell.

Comment: yes, you are right, it was inside of a table, and only the table had an id, neither the row or cell it was in had an id, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

myControl2 is probably higher up in the hierarchy; keep drilling up the hierarchy to find the control, it may be `mycontrol1.Parent.Parent` or more parent references.  ASP.NET sometimes puts other controls in the hierarchy and so it may not be a direct parent.

HTH.

Comment: You are quite correct, thank you; i just discovered this when it told me i had an answer, i didn't stop to think that, my check boxes are inside of a table... which means there is a row and a cell for which i gave no id. Explaining why it did recognize that there was a parent, but i was asking for something that didn't exist    thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Do you have runat="server" when you create the checkboxes?

Comment: Every ASP.NET-Control like CheckBox is `runat="server"` implicitely. http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/whyrunatserverforaspnetpart2/

Comment: It is if you are using the toolbox to add them. If you're manually typing out the aspx, it will not have it unless you type it.

Comment: @Rezler(use @-sign to address people, otherwise they get no info): If you don't add `runat="server"` in codebehind, it'll get it automatically. If you leave it out of the aspx-markup you will get an ASP.NET Exception. But the OP mentioned that he'd added the CheckBox dynamically(means from codebehind), hence he does not need to add it manually.

Comment: Yes you are correct (I skipped over the part where he was adding it dynamically. I still think your original comment is not 100% true as it is too general.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling this test method. Consider calling it onPreRender and it should return the ID. When you dynamically create control and add to page, and if don't assign nny ID, .net assign them before rendering to browser